# Is there something like runDB but outside the Handler monad?

Tags: haskell, websocket, yesod

I'm developing a web application using Yesod 1.2 where I'm using websockets. The requests made to a websocket need to query my database, and to make this queries I know they have to be within a `PersistStore` instance. As far as I know I can't use `runDB` because the websockets request handlers aren't within the `Handler` monad. Instead, for this I could use something similar to the code in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031607/yesod-websockets-and-persistent) question.

Which is the cleanest way to get within a `PersistStore` monad in a scaffolded site? I know I could easily shoot `runSqlite` with a hard-coded connection string and be done with it, but I think this is ugly. If by any reason I want to change the database engine I don't want to modify every piece of code where I make a connection to the database.

I'm looking for a way of using what the scaffolded site already does for me when it connects to the database so as not to repeat code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to run this is the same way that the scaffolded site [runs the migration code](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/20fd6428aacff4b1f6745aee424ddbdedf4ee11e/Application.hs#L74):

```
-- Perform database migration using our application's logging settings.
runLoggingT
    (Database.Persist.runPool dbconf (runMigration migrateAll) p)
    (messageLoggerSource foundation logger)
```